# Parallax effect – hero image overlayed/stack by content

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I came across the website for the Moonlight Movie: http://moonlight.movie/

In the top there is a fullscreen image, when scrolling this is being overlayed by a fullscreen section.

It is a niffty little parallax-like effect, that also works on mobile (ios)

Does anybody know how to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to check [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/) or the [parallax fullPage.js extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/parallax.html) with an offset of 100%.

If you opt to use `pagePiling.js` [here's an article](https://www.onextrapixel.com/how-to-create-a-beautiful-fullscreen-single-scrolling-page-like-huge-inc/) that explains how to achieve something similar with it.

[Reproduction online](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/NPojPX)

Comment: Thanks I will try these - they seem to be something that could work